# Spring Integration :Can we have two Inbound Channel in the same time

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using

```
    <int:inbound-channel-adapter id="dummyMessageA" channel="messages" method="getMessage" auto-startup="true" ref="messageGenerator">
       <int:poller error-channel="errorChannel" fixed-rate="10000"/>
    </int:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:inbound-channel-adapter id="dummyNotif" channel="notifs" method="gtNotif" auto-startup="true" ref="notifGenerator">
        <int:poller error-channel="errorChannel" fixed-rate="10000"/>
    </int:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

These inbound channels are independent but when I deploy my Web Application, Only the second inbound channel adapter is taken into consideration (although the other one was working before adding the dummyNotif). Is this normal, should I add something in the config (NB : I don't aggregate the messages)

Answer (score 0):

My guess you catched this issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3240 - 'Inbound Channel Adapter Parser doesn't generate unique bean Id for MessageSources'. That's mean that you use Spring Integration 3.0.

So, just upgrade to the latest - **3.0.2.RELEASE** - and let us know.

**UPDATE**

Regarding the same `id` for several beans. By default Spring allow to do it and the last bean wins. All others will be ignored and skipped.

It can be disabled by `AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext#setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false)`.

From other side if you setup DEBUG logging level for `org.springframework` category you'll the message in the logs that your beans are overriden.

Comment: I am working with Spring-integrtion 4.0.0.M4. And I fix the problem, by cleaning my project. But I was wondering why spring didn't detect that i am defining two Service activator with the same Id? By error I did it but my application was deploying but only one of them were working and I haven't understand the problem as no exception is thrown until I have seen that the same id is used.

Answer (score 0):

as far as your question is concerned, `Spring Integration` allows to have multiple `inbound-channel-adapter` definition in a single context.

However, from your comments, seems that you have some different issue in your configuration `multiple Service Activators with same Id`.
It can be disabled as @Artem described in his answer.

Comment: Yes now it is working, I have updated my project and fixed the duplicated id. Now every think is fine :)